# Creating multiple numeric input according to the variables of an uploaded dataset

Tags: file-upload, dynamic, shiny, insert-update, numeric-input

I am working on a Shiny app that allows the user to upload their own data and analyze them. At a certain point, I'd like to allow the user to introduce new data as numeric input and to build a new table including them.

I'd like my app to do it dynamically, i.e. creating a box in the sidebar panel containing new numeric input accordingly and with the name of the variables of my uploaded dataset.

I can do it by indicating *a priori* specific variables, but I'd like to make it dynamic.

I'd be really glad if somebody could attend to this matter.
Here's included a simple example of my code and a screenshot showing how it looks like (but with *a priori* specified variables).

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  tabPanel("New Cases", icon=icon("edit"),
           sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(width=3, #sidebarPanel "New Cases"
                        conditionalPanel(
                            'input.dataset02 === "Edit Table"',
                            textInput('NewID', HTML('<h5><b>Enter Name</b></h5>')), #Enter Factor?
                            numericInput('NewVal1', HTML('<h5><b>Enter Item</b></h5>'), NULL),
                            br(),
                            fluidRow(
                              column(2,  HTML('<h5><b>E14</b></h5>')),
                              column(4, numericInput("NewVal3", label = NULL, value = NULL)),
                              column(2, HTML('<h5><b>E16</b></h5>')), 
                              column(4, numericInput("NewVal4", label = NULL, value = NULL))
                            ),
                            fluidRow(
                              column(2, HTML('<h5><b>E18_1</b></h5>')),
                              column(4, numericInput("NewVal5", label = NULL, value = NULL)),
                              column(2,  HTML('<h5><b>E18</b></h5>')), 
                              column(4, numericInput("NewVal6", label = NULL, value = NULL))
                            ),
                            fluidRow(
                              column(2, HTML('<h5><b>FAEE</b></h5>')),
                              column(4, numericInput("NewVal7", label = NULL, value = NULL)),
                              column(2,  HTML('<h5><b>EtG</b></h5>')), 
                              column(4, numericInput("NewVal8", label = NULL, value = NULL))
                            ),
                            br(),
                            actionButton("goButton", "Update Table",icon("cloud-upload"), 
                                         style="width: 100%; height: 60px; color: steelblue; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"),
                            br()
                          )),
             mainPanel(
               tabsetPanel(
                 id = 'dataset02',
                 tabPanel("Edit Table",
                          br(),
                          dataTableOutput("table3"))
                 ))
           )))
server <- function(input, output) {
  mydata3 = data.frame(Name=letters[NULL], Item=sample(NULL),Piece=sample(NULL), E14=sample(NULL), E16=sample(NULL), 
                       E18_1=sample(NULL), E18=sample(NULL), FAEE=sample(NULL), ETG=sample(NULL))
  output$table3 <- renderDataTable( df3())
  df3 <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    if(input$NewID!=" " && !is.null(input$NewVal1)
       && !is.null(input$NewVal3) && !is.null(input$NewVal4) && !is.null(input$NewVal5) 
       && !is.null(input$NewVal6) && !is.null(input$NewVal7) && !is.null(input$NewVal8) 
       && input$goButton>0)
      {
      newrow = data.frame(
        Name = input$NewID,
        Item = input$NewVal1,           
        Piece = 1,                      
        E14 = input$NewVal3,
        E16 = input$NewVal4,
        E18_1 = input$NewVal5,
        E18 = input$NewVal6,
        FAEE = input$NewVal7,
        ETG = input$NewVal8)
      mydata3 <<- rbind(mydata3, newrow)
    }
    mydata3
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

#### Screenshot of the app (in the "desired" format) is the following:

[image: Screenshot of the app]

Answer (score 0):

You can create inputs dynamically with `renderUI` and `uiOutput`.

Example:

```
# LIBRARIES & SOURCING --------------
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# UI -----------------
ui <- dashboardPage(title="App Title", 
                    dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE),
                    dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
                    dashboardBody( 
                        fluidRow(
                            uiOutput("uiOut1")
                        )
))

# SERVER -----------------
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$uiOut1 = renderUI(
        list(
            numericInput("dynInput1", "First dynamic input:", 20, 0, 40),
            numericInput("dynInput2", "Second dynamic input:", 20, 0, 40)
        )
    )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

You can then refer to the inputs with `input$dynInput1` or `input[["dynInput1"]]` if you need to use a variable to select which input you want.

More info here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html